# How to send aa GET request from a ktor server?

Tags: kotlin, heroku, ktor

I am a beginner making my first ktor server. I have a functional website that allows users to push data to the server. Next, I need the server to push that data to the database. The way I am trying to accomplish this now is by sending a get request with the data as a query parameter from the server to the database.

First I searched "ktor send get request", and found https://ktor.io/docs/request.html but this is listed under the "ktor client" and doesn't seem to have a counterpart in "ktor server".

Next, I tried doing a basic HTTP request with java. I used

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.net.http.HttpResponse
```

to send a get request the same way you would in plain old java. And since these references resolved just fine in the IDE, I thought I was good to go. But when I tried to deploy the server to heroku, I got

```
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (23, 17): Unresolved reference: http
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (24, 17): Unresolved reference: http
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (25, 17): Unresolved reference: http
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (119, 16): Unresolved reference: HttpClient
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (120, 17): Unresolved reference: HttpRequest
remote:        e: /tmp/build_c9454b1c/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt: (124, 39): Unresolved reference: HttpResponse
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your backend can both serve as a `server` to the clients / website and be a `client` himself, e.g. in respect to contacting the database. There is nothing wrong with that. In the contrary, it's a wide spread pattern. Thus, you can include and use both the `server` and `client` packages from ktor inside your backend.

Comment: What version of Java is running on Heroku? `HttpClient` was added in Java 11. Anyway, I suggest going with `ktor-client`. You really should use library that support coroutines/suspending and you can't get this from Java libs.

Comment: @Endzeit I was wondering about that. That should do it! Broot, I don't know what version of java heroku uses, but locally i use 16. That's probably what is occuring. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Enzeit and @Broot explained to me in the comments, I can just use ktor-client in my server as well.